# JavaScript unexpected string using Dictionary Collection

Tags: javascript, string, collections, syntax-error

creating a short menu using collections. If you run the code it works fine, but when I go back and insert this piece of code into any menuItem the result is an unexpected string. I can't figure out if there is actually a string issue or if by adding additional values caused error in some way. I've been looking at for a while and I can't seem to find any improperly formatted strings.

```
added in for 'menuItem1'
'description': ['test1', test2', test3', test4']
```

added in description to function below:

```
function cheeseBurger() 
document.getElementById("description").innerHTML="";
```

**This for loop is nested inside the 1st for loop. I don't know if that is correct or not yet because i can't get the code to run, but it seems after its done counting the ingredients that it would then hop into the next loop and repeat for description, and hopefully not infinitely, not so good with nested loops yet.**

```
for (var i = 0; i < menu.menuitem1.description.length; i++) 
{
   document.getElementById("description").innerHTML 
   += "<p>"  +  menu.menuitem1.description[i] + "</p>";
}
```

```js
var menu = {
  'menuitem1' : {
   'name' : 'Cheeseburger',
   'price' : '5.90',
   'ingredients' : ['Ketchup','Mayo','Lettuce','Tomato']
   
  },
  'menuitem2' : {
   'name' : 'Pizza',
   'price' : '7.50',
   'ingredients' : ['Peppers','Italian Sausage','Peppers','Bacon']
   
  },
  'menuitem3' : {
   'name' : 'Hotdog',
   'price' : '3.50',
   'ingredients' : ['Mustard','Sauerkraut','Ketchup','Grilled Onions']
   
  },
  'menuitem4' : {
   'name' : 'Salad',
   'price' : '4.65',
   'ingredients' : ['Mangos','Apple',' Cheese','Side of Dressing']
    
  }
 };


function cheeseBurger() {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = menu.menuitem1.name;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = menu.menuitem1.price;
  document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < menu.menuitem1.ingredients.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML
             += "<p>" +    menu.menuitem1.ingredients[i] + "</p>";
  }
  
 }
 function pizza() {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = menu.menuitem2.name;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = menu.menuitem2.price;
  document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < menu.menuitem2.ingredients.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML += "<p>" + menu.menuitem2.ingredients[i] + "</p>";
   
  }
 }
 function hotDog() {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = menu.menuitem3.name;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = menu.menuitem3.price;
  document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < menu.menuitem3.ingredients.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML 
           += "<p>" + menu.menuitem3.ingredients[i] + "</p>";
   
  }
 }
 function salad() {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = menu.menuitem4.name;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = menu.menuitem4.price;
  document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < menu.menuitem4.ingredients.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById("ingredients").innerHTML 
            += "<p>" + menu.menuitem4.ingredients[i] + "</p>";
   
  }
 }
```

Comment: `'description': ['test1', test2', test3', test4']` should be `'description': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']`. Missing 3 `'`.

Comment: @imtheman i went  in and made those changes, but I am still receiving the same result of "unexpected string" no other error messages are popping up. Did you notice anything else syntactically wrong? Thanks for your help and input